# Ubuntu 14.04 nautilus icons size

Tags: unity, 14.04, nautilus, icons

After upgrading to ubuntu 14.04 from 13.10, I tried a bit of tweaks. Not sure which tweak was responsible but now I have nautilus icons that are very small. Though in the preferences the icons size is set to 100% still the icons appear very small. What can I do to restore them to their proper size?

Though I have a strong feeling that the Setting under Display: "Scale all window contents to match" might be the cause but even now when I have set it to "Display with largest controls", there's no difference.

Answer (score 3):

If you hold down the Ctrl key and use the scroll wheel this increases the size of the icons.

If you're talking about your desktop icons you can fix it like this:

- Go into edit | preferences | Views
- click on the "Icon View Defaults" percentage and make it larger

If you're talking about the icons in the nautilus browser you can fix it like this:

- Open nautilus
- hold down the  key, and use your mouse's scroll wheel to increase or decrease the zoom level in the browser

Hope that helps!

Comment: Nopes that doesn't help.. As I've already mentioned in preferences Icon view is set to 100% and that works fine for folder and some icons. But for other icons the size is really small. I think I am not making myself clear, but couldn't post a screenshot of my problem as I don't have enough credits. Anyways thanks for your time ...